# Embed non-shared folder

Tags: box-api

Can a folder that has not been shared be used by the embed widget?

We have a web-application in which we would like to use the embed widget to enable our customers to access their own Box account.  Because it would be their own account, it's really not necessary to share the folders.  There would be many folders (a few for each of **their** customers) for which our app would use the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I'll admit it is a bit confusing. You can generate a "Box Embed Widget" for a folder that you are the only collaborator on.  That essentially doesn't share the file with anyone, even though it calls it a "share".  If you try to not have it generate a "shared link" then it won't let you create the widget.

So the answer is 99% Yes, because you can get the behavior that you want.  Here's how:

Go to the website to a private folder.   Select the dropdown arrow next to the folder, --> then "Share" -->  then "Embed Folder in your site".   It will pop up the Box-embed-widget dialog.

You can choose a bunch of options, from the size of the widget, to it's color and layout.  You can also select to have it only shared with yourself.  Make sure you change the share level from "Open" to "Collaborators only".

Comment: I also recommend checking out these two resources. This is how to do embed via the GUI http://success.box.com/best-practices/box-embed/. You can also check out paramaters you can set via this link: http://developers.box.com/box-embed/. Documentation on how to do this programmatically do this can be shared as well, if you're interested.